# Swiftの {}()の意味は？

Tags: swift

Swiftで以下のようなコードがあります。

```
var videoBitrateLabel:UILabel = {
    let label:UILabel = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return label }()
```

これでできたインスタンスは後ほどaddSubviewします。

```
view.addSubview(videoBitrateLabel)
```

ぱっと見で、このようなものだと理解はできるのですが、{}と()の意味(効果?)を教えてください。
またGoogleで調べるのに何と調べればわかるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

以下のように書いたのと同じになります。
引数なし、戻り値がUILabel、inの後ろから}までが本体となるクロージャ式(closure expression)です。
swiftの型推論機能などにより、() -> UILabel inは省略することができます。
引数と戻り値の数などによっては、省略できない場合もあります。
最後の()はクロージャ式を実行しています。

```
var videoBitrateLabel:UILabel = {() -> UILabel in 
    let label:UILabel = UILabel()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return label
}()
```

Comment: {}は型推論したクロージャ式ですね。理解できました。しかし、この書き方は何か有効性があるのでしょうか？var videoBitrateLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)); videoBitrateLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor(); self.view.addSubview(videoBitrateLabel); と記載した方が短くてわかり易いと思いますが何か意味があるのでしょうか？ご存知であれば教えてください。

Comment: var videoBitrateLabelがどこに定義されているものなのか分からないのでなんとも言えませんが、クラスのプロパティなのであれば、このように書くと定義時に同時に値を設定できます。
init内で設定するのとどちらがいいかは議論が分かれるかも知れません。
私の好みとしては、宣言時にクロージャを使うことはないですかね。

varの前にlazyをつけることによって、プロパティ呼び出しで初めてメモリアロケートされるようになるので、メモリ消費量をわずかに抑える効果があるようです。
http://mikebuss.com/2014/06/22/lazy-initialization-swift/